# $ F(x)= \int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} e^{t^2+xt}\,dt$. What is $F'(0)=$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\begin{align*} F(x)&= \int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} e^{t^2+xt}\,\mathrm dt\\F'(0)&=\,?\end{align*}$$

I only know how to deal with the kind like $$F(x)=\int h(x)g(t)\,\mathrm dt $$ for which I can treat $h(x)$ as a constant relative to $t$ and move it out of the integral and differentiate. But in this problem I cannot separate $x$ from $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be given by

$$F(x)=\int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)}e^{t^2+xt}\,dt$$

Using [Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we have

$$\begin{align}
F'(x)&=\left.\left(e^{t^2+tx}\right)\right|_{t=\cos(x)}\left(\frac{d\cos(x)}{dx}\right)-\left.\left(e^{t^2+tx}\right)\right|_{t=\sin(x)}\left(\frac{d\sin(x)}{dx}\right)\\\\
&+\int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)}\frac{\partial \left(e^{t^2+xt}\right)}{\partial x}\,dt\\\\
&=-\sin(x)e^{\cos^2(x)+x\cos(x)}-\cos(x)e^{\sin^2(x)+x\sin(x)}+\int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)}te^{t^2+xt}\,dt\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Setting $x=0$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
F'(0)&=-1+\int_0^1te^{t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=-1+\frac12(e^1-1)\\\\
&=\frac12(e^1-3)
\end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) This is correct, but I had a hard time reading it. I hope you don't mind that I tried to compose a similar approach.

Comment: @robjohn Rob, thank you.  And of course I don't mind.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this rule before.

Comment: Dr. MV and robjohn, both answers are correct of course. At the same time I feel it is important that students should not blindly memorize "rules" or "formulas" but learn the idea behind it.    Leibniz's Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral is just a simple application of the chain rule and the FTC.  If you understand the idea behind the formula, then you can differentiate $$F(x,y)=\int^{y\cos (x)}_{y^2\sin x}e^{t^2+xt}dt$$ or $$F(x)=\int^{\cos (x)}_{\sin x}\int_{t}_{x+1}e^{y^2+xy}dydt$$

Comment: Sorry I meant too write $$F(x)=\int^{\cos (x)}_{\sin x}\int^{t}_{x+1}e^{y^2+xy}dydt$$ but was too slow. Oh well... just a comment. Math.stackexchange is more frustrating than I thought. Probably won't stay long...

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if this is just Dr. MV's idea, but I hope this is a simpler exposition.

Using $v=\cos(x)$, $u=\sin(x)$, and $y=t^2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)}e^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\int_u^ve^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t
-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\int_u^ve^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t
+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_u^ve^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{v^2+xv}
-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{u^2+xu}
+\int_u^vte^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\sin(x)e^{\cos^2(x)+x\cos(x)}
-\cos(x)e^{\sin^2(x)+x\sin(x)}
+\int_{\sin(x)}^{\cos(x)}te^{t^2+xt}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-0-1+\int_0^1te^{t^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-1+\frac12\int_0^1e^y\mathrm{d}y\\[3pt]
&=\frac12e-\frac32
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function of three variables
$$g(x,y,z)=\int_z^y e^{t^2+xt}\,dt.$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, you know that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y,z)=e^{y^2+xy},$ while $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(x,y,z)=-e^{z^2+xz}$. Also  $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=\int_z^y  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{t^2+xt})dt=\int_z^yt (e^{t^2+xt})\,dt.$
Now your function is the composition $g(x,\cos x,\sin x)$ and so you can use the chain rule to find that
$$F'(x)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,\cos x,\sin x)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,\cos x,\sin x)(-\sin x)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(x,\cos x,\sin x)  (\cos x).$$